# Return a new object as return value in java

Tags: java

```
public class myMethod {
      public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int length = nums.length;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++)
            {
                if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
                    return new int[]{i,j};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It show "error: missing return statement".
I have returned an Array, where is the problem? 
Do I need such like Array.newInstance() ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you return if `nums` has length 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return any value in case the content of your `if` block is never reached.

You can return a `default` value like this:

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
  ...
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for remind me that, a method must at least have a exit for all cases.